# Trying to convert text to nested dict in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, data-structures

I am trying to get a nested dict from a list of phrases.

My phrases for example are:

> show version
> show module
> show module 0 det
> show running-config

I am expecting a structure like this:

```
"show":{
        "version":None,
        "module":{
            "0": {
                "det"
               }
        },
        "running-config":None
    }
```

What I am trying is: split the phrases, from each array I am converting it to Dict.

```
for line in commandsOrdered:
    value = line[-1]
    line.pop(-1)
    for key in list(reversed(line[:])):
        value = {key: value}
        sL.append(value)
```

And once I have a list of dicts, I am merging the dictionaries.

```
super_dict = {}
for d in sL:
    for k, v in d.items(): 
        super_dict.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

But I am getting this:

```
{
    "show": [
        "module",
        {
            "module": {
                "0": "det"
            }
        },
        "running-config",
        "version"
    ],
    "0": [
        "det"
    ],
    "module": [
        {
            "0": "det"
        }
    ]
}
```

The max depth I have is 9 words in a phrase.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Is `{"det"}` supposed to be `{"det": None}`?

Comment: No, with {"det"} is enough, but it doesn't matter, boths ways are ok.

Comment: "with {"det"} is enough" - that makes no sense, you cannot have a key in a dictionary without a value. Do you want the inner-most dicts to be sets or lists instead? Or do you expect some kind of value for the keys?

Comment: `{"det"}` is a set. What makes `show module 0 det` a set but not the other leaf nodes?

Comment: Also I am assuming that `sL` is a `list` (we don't see where it is constructed) but you don't expect to have a `list` in your expected output.

Comment: well, it was for simplicity, but yeah, to make the structure, I can add {"det":None}

Comment: I literally just created one line before the for. sL = []

Comment: @csr23 Allowing `"det": None` makes it a lot easier :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this is fairly straightforward:

```
commandsOrdered = [
    'show version',
    'show module',
    'show module 0 det',
    'show running-config'
]

result = {}
for command in commandsOrdered:
    parts = command.split()
    d = result
    for key in parts[:-1]:
        if key not in d or not d[key]:
            d[key] = {}
        d = d[key]
    d[parts[-1]] = None

print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'show': {'version': None, 'module': {'0': {'det': None}}, 'running-config': None}}
```

Not using `defaultdict` to meet the `None` requirement. You could easily write this recursively as well though, given the limited depth. That would make for simpler code, but not a faster solution per se.